# Can I use Databricks Connect with a cluster configured with port 443?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

My company is using Databricks hosted in Azure Government. The default port for a cluster is 443 which I understand is HTTPS.

After configuring my environment variables and running databricks-connect test the command successfully spins up the cluster if it is in a terminated state BUT once it turns on the test fails.

Partial error message:

The port you specified is either being used already or invalid.
Port: The port that Databricks Connect connects to

- The default Databricks Connect port is 15001
- Get current value: spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.port")
- Set via conf: spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.service.port", ")

When I manually change the cluster's port to 15001 and set the port environment variable accordingly databricks-connect test is successful.

I am no expert on network security. Is there a way I can keep the cluster on port 443 and still utilize Databricks Connect?

Comment: Did you managed to set the configuration to 443? Because locally I can use 15001, but on my production Kube cluster, the firewall blocks 15001 port. I tried to change databricks configuration to 443, but it fails even locally.